# Filling array with data intersection (fixed window size)

Tags: arrays, pandas, intersection

I have numbers from 1 to 30, I put them in array of fixed lenth=10
and here what I have initially:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

What I need is fixed size window=7, there should be data intersection, so that I will have 5 rows instead of 3 (1-10, 8-17, 15-24, 22-30, 29-30):

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
15  16 17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
22  23 24  25  26  27  28  29  30   0
29  30  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have no idea how to implement this...
Could somebody please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: this is not clear. the output should be 5 rows and 7 columns. right?

Comment: 5 rows and 10 columns, as in example. We should use "window" to fill array and window size is 7, while length of array is 10...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method come in my mind

```
Newdf=pd.DataFrame(data=df.values.ravel(),index=np.arange(len(df.values.ravel()))//7)
n=10-7

s=Newdf.groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
s
Out[824]:
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6
0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0
1   8.0   9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
2  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0  21.0
3  22.0  23.0  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0
4  29.0  30.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

pd.concat([s,s.iloc[:,:n].shift(-1)],1).fillna(0)
Out[832]: 
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     0     1     2
0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0
1   8.0   9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  16.0  17.0
2  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0
3  22.0  23.0  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0  30.0   0.0
4  29.0  30.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Genius! I would spend years for it) Thank you!

Comment: @elenaby yw:-) happy coding